# "original error: platform doesnt exist android-4.2" error when using selendroid device capability

Tags: android, appium

Using the android sdk(adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130729), appiumforwindows+0.8.3, when ran an appium test on android emulator with selendroid capability, it gave "aapt" not found error, so copied the aapt.exe&lib to platform-tools folder in sdk dir. this error got fixed but giving error, 
"original error: platform doesnt exist android-4.2"

i understand it could be selendroid/android issue; really appreciate if anyone can suggest any thoughts to fix this error..

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, selendroid is looking for Android 4.2 and i had 4.3 installed. Installing 4.2 as well is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem some time ago, the solution for me was to install the Java SDK and the Android ADT-Package into a location **without any blanks**.

Before it was on "C:\Program Files...", which caused Appium to not find the aapt.exe, although the ANDROID_HOME and the Path Variables were set correctly. I found a hint about that somewhere on the Appium Github.

Answer (score 0):

If you use selendroid directly, lately improvements especially for Windows has been added.

The support for blanks in folder names is build in the current version 0.7.0:
https://github.com/selendroid/selendroid/releases/download/0.7.0/selendroid-standalone-0.7.0-with-dependencies.jar